# How to bind any patricular object property in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angular1.6

I am new to angular 1.6 component architecture and having a simple problem. I am having one **`src`** object with having two properties within it i.e. `name` and `age`.
    Now, what I want is binding that name property in html.

```
The following is the code:
```

***test.js:-***

```
$ctrl.src = {
    details: [
      { Id: 1, Name: "Test1", Address: "Add1" },
      { Id: 2, Name: "Test2", Address: "Add2" }
    ]
  };

test.html:-

    <cell-component>Hi {{Name}}</cell-component>


Expected Output:-

    Hi test
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `$scope.src` refers to a object with two properties, angular model binding always requires to specify the object key in the view together with the object name like this

```
  {{src.Name}} //renders $scope.src.Name
  {{src.Age}} //renders $scope.src.Age
```

So your view needs to be changed to

```
<cell-component>Hi {{src.Name}}</cell-component>
```

There is also another way to access the properties and render them in view.

```
  {{src['Name']}} //renders $scope.src.Name
  {{src['Age']}} //renders $scope.src.Age
```

Which leads to

```
 <cell-component>Hi {{src['Name']}}</cell-component>
```

Comment: Down voter explain the reason for voting it down. People are really terrible here.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to access the properties of particular object, You shoulse use dot operator like below

```
<cell-component>Hi {{src.Name}}</cell-component>
```

**EDIT**

With your modification details is an array where you need to specify the index you want to display

```
 <cell-component>Hi {{src.details[0].Name}}</cell-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple thing you can do is you just have to put ng-repeate on src.details and print each object in it.
i.e.
 `<div ng-repeate="obj in src.details"><div>{{obj.Name}}</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to take the src object on scope to get it into view as expression.

> 'src' is an object having property named 'details' which itself is an array of objects. So you have to go down according to the object hierarchy to get the value of property 'Name'. But 'Name' is an property under 'details' which is an array so you must iterate over it using ng-repeat or simply specify the array index.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.src = {
    details: [
      { Id: 1, Name: "Test1", Address: "Add1" },
      { Id: 2, Name: "Test2", Address: "Add2" }
    ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h3>Hi {{src.details[0].Name}}</h3>
    <h3>Hi {{src.details[1].Name}}</h3>
    
    <h3 ng-repeat="obj in src.details">Hi {{obj.Name}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```